# Upload images to Google Photos in high (not original) quality from the web

Tags: google-photos, image-storage

Google Photos features [two storage classes](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en):

- **High quality** - Unlimited free storage.
- **Original** - Limited free storage

My phone backup mode is set to High Quality, so I have no space problems with it. However, when I upload images from the web console, they are kept in their Original quality.

**Is there a way to upload images to [Google Photos](http://photos.google.com) via the web interface in High, not Original, quality?**

P.S., Google Photos allows me to compress the uploaded images after they have been uploaded, but I'm looking for a way to automate the process, rather than remembering to compress after I upload.

[image: compression notification]

Comment: Are you using the desktop uploader? That uploads your photos in the background without any intervention from you. You just need to point it at your local photos director(y|ies).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Settings](https://photos.google.com/settings), you can set whether web uploads are "High Quality" or "Original".

[image: upload quality setting]